# wrong number of arguments ruby rspec

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm trying to write unit tests for my code using rspec.  I keep getting a "wrong number of arguments" error:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :env, :company,:size, :role, :number_of_hosts,:visability

  def initialize(env, company, size, role, number_of_hosts, visability)
    @env, @company, @size, @role, @number_of_hosts, @visability =  env, company, size, role, number_of_hosts, visability
  end




end
```

And here are my tests:

```
require_relative "../lib/MyClass.rb"

 describe MyClass do
    it "has an environment" do
        MyClass.new("environment").env.should respond_to :env
    end

    it "has a company" do
        MyClass.new("company").company.should respond_to :company
    end

...
```

When I run rspec I get:

```
1) MyClass has an environment
     Failure/Error: MyClass.new("environment").env.should respond_to :env
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 6)
     # ./lib/MyClass.rb:4:in `initialize'
     # ./spec/MyClass_spec.rb:5:in `new'
     # ./spec/MyClass_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

...

What am I missing?

EDIT

Sergio helped thanks...however

Sergio's answer worked...although I still have a further question:

Given the Class:

```
class Team
    attr_accessor :name, :players

    def initialize(name, players = [])
        raise Exception unless players.is_a? Array

        @name = name
        raise Exception if @name && has_bad_name

        @players = players
    end

    def has_bad_name
        list_of_words = %w{crappy bad lousy}
        list_of_words - @name.downcase.split(" ") != list_of_words
    end

    def favored?
        @players.include? "George Clooney"
    end

end
```

and spec...

```
require_relative "../lib/team.rb"

describe Team do
    it "has a name" do
        Team.new("random name").should respond_to :name
    end

    it "has a list of players" do
        Team.new("random name").players.should be_kind_of Array
    end
```

...

The tests pass without the same error...(This works fine: Team.new("random name"))

Any explanation?

Comment: You're missing 5 more arguments to the constructor.

Comment: you mean like, MyClass.new("company","blah","blah","blah","blah") ??

Comment: Yeah, something like that

Comment: I edited my question...can you explain why I needed to add multiple arguments?

Comment: Your second spec worked because second parameter (`players`) has a default value. So if you don't pass a value for it, it defaults to empty array. In your first spec you don't have default values for any parameters, so you have to pass them all.

Comment: -1 for changing the question after posting it instead of posting a new question for the additional question you've had. That's considered rude here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the error `MyClass.new("environment")`. As you have written `def initialize(env, company, size, role, number_of_hosts, visability)`. So you should pass `6` parameters when you are calling `MyClass#new` method. But in practice you pass only one which is `"environment"`. Thus you got the legitimate error - ***wrong number of arguments (1 for 6)***.

Comment: Yeah, that's what rspec said... mind explaining _why_ he got the error (hint, there is a comment that already says that)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Comment is not an answer,, its a hint.. right? I think my answer is appropriate for this post.. But don't know why so many down-votes..

Comment: Hmmm can't cancel the down vote yet, all it said when I read it was the first sentence. :(

Comment: Why should I not @TonyHopkinson ? I was writing the answer and saving it.. meanwhile I got 2 down-votes.. Do you think *Here is the error `MyClass.new("environment")`*, line is not a good catch to answer to the error as an first attempt?

Comment: I edited my question...can you explain why I needed to add multiple arguments?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I receded my down vote as soon as you edited your answer to include information about the problem over the message OP got.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I am very upset with this kind of down votes..:( ...people didn't withdraw their down-votes from this answer,while this one answers the requested problem...

Comment: @ArupRakshit: On the other hand, you shouldn't be posting half-baked (even less than so) answers with typos just to claim first answer. Maybe that explains some downvotes. I like to be first answerer too, but I strive to post usable answers in revision 0.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev we don't entertain in SO,to edit post after 6-7 mins(when answer has been given) and then change the question...

Comment: No I think that just the first sentence as answer to the question is completely a crap answer, which is why I down voted it. Something I rarely do by the way. Can't cancel my down vote unless you do an edit, as 21 hours have passed apparently. If you do that, I will, and we'll let two honest mistakes cancel each other out.

Comment: Sorted, you've gone well positive now